# What is the difference between panel and blog in Drupal?

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to find content holder for my site home page and came across the concept of panels. But I didn't found anything for user permission in panels.

Can anyone help me understanding the difference between panel and blog around user permission?

Comment: Please could you clarify what you mean? A 'blog' item is a node and a panel is...well, not a node. They're not comparable concepts so it's difficult to know how to answer your question at the moment

Comment: Are you sure you mean _blog_ and not _block_?

Comment: Yes, I am unable to find much on blog. Can anyone please explain. I had seen blog selected as a node type in context setting, but didn't get that how blog is related to page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Panle can load many things and you can set permission of each block or something that panel is loading. SO its would be better if you use panels and filter with roles that you want. You need to clearly define the question !!

Comment: Actually I am searching for content holder alternative for page layout which should be more flexible in terms of user permission. In panels we can set permission of block or view but not for particular panel section or region. For example if my page layout is 3 column and I want only one section out of three would be visible to particular set of people then how can I achieve  that ? I am not able to set permission for a particular panel section.

Comment: Also it would be really helpful if someone can explain me the significant difference between block and panel in terms of user permission.

Answer (score 0):

Panel is a type of node that can use pre-defined templates for layout and CSS. A panel can contains multiple references to node.

A Blog Page is an other type of node. You can add content HTML in this type of node, with a title and a teaser. If you want to style the content, you should make CSS ans HTML.

Panel is simplest but louder. For the security, they are both Node ...

A Block is a zone that can contain different kinds of content; text, (part of ) menu, ...

Here is a little presentation about [block and panel on slideshare](http://fr.slideshare.net/davexoxide/drupal-blocks-vs-context-vs-panels)

Comment: How I can use context for page layout?